# Wordpress prettyphoto lightbox not displaying title. Showing undefined instead

Tags: jquery, wordpress, undefined, lightbox, prettyphoto

http://atemporarysite.co.uk/?page_id=226#!prettyPhoto

Above is the link to my Wordpress gallery page. How do I get rid of the text 'undefined' which shows up under the image, after clicking on it?

I have tried for hours to work out where that is coming from. When I do the inspect element, it seems to point to prettyphoto.css but that is standard, we should not have to change that.

You guys are my only hope. Any help would be SO GREATLY appreciated
thanks,
Una

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities. If you only want to hide "undefined", you can add for class `.pp_description`  `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none !important;`. Using `!important` is necessary because `display:block` is added to the description element by the gallery script.
 If you want to have copy instead of `undefined`, you can try to add a `title` attribute to the link wrapping the image as it looks like `jquery.prettyPhoto.js` is setting the description copy from this title attribute which is not set. For reference: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/:

> To display a description, add the description into the TITLE
>   attribute of your link.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt help and that should work yes. I went in and changed the
prettyphoto.css to read


div.pp_default .pp_description {
    display: none!important
}

Saved my changes
But in the browser it still shows up the same.

as somehow the browser is not accepting the changes as when I do inspect element again, my changes dont show. yet when I go back in Wordpress dashboard, and into Appearance, editor the changes show.
I find that weird.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ah, it is working now (finally that horrible 'undefined' is GONE at last. Thanks to your help !
I think it was just taking my website server a long time to register the changes with the browser
THANK YOU SO MUCH, and hope this thread helps anyone else who has this problem.